# Debugger breakpoints do influence on generated sql query by Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, debugging, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I try move sub Entity C (detail) from my Entity A (project) to Entity B (project)

1. I put sub Entity C (detail)  to temp variable
2. set empty Entity C (detail) for  Entity A
3. save Entity A using JpaRepository
4. set temp variable data to Entity B
5. save Entity B using JpaRepository

This work properly only when I put breakpoint on step 3:  save Entity A using JpaRepository. I can see delete then insert query in final log:

```
Hibernate: delete from project_details where project_id=? 
...
Hibernate: insert into project_details (project_id, details_id) values (?, ?)
```

but without breakpoint on step 3 I just lost Entity C (detail) in both entities (only delete in query log) 
How can I need to fix that to work properly without breakpoint?

```
    @Transactional
    public void moveProject(final AtomicReference<Project> projectRecipient, final Project projectMoved) {
        Project projectRecipientDB = projectRepository.findOne(projectRecipient.get().getId());
        Project projectMovedDB = projectRepository.findOne(projectMoved.getId());

        Set<ProjectDetail> projectDetailsCurrent = projectMovedDB.getDetails();
        projectMovedDB.setDetails(new HashSet<>());
        projectRepository.save(projectMovedDB); //breakpoint 
        projectRepository.flush();

        projectRecipientDB.setDetails(mergeSet(projectRecipientDB.getDetails(), projectDetailsCurrent));
        projectRepository.save(projectRecipientDB);
        projectRepository.flush();

    }
```

UPD: I somehow made this code work, I just put

```
Set<ProjectDetail> projectDetailsCurrent = projectMovedDB.getDetails(); 
Logger.getLogger(ProjectService.class.getName()).error("projectDetailsCurrent2 size = "+projectDetailsCurrent.size() ); 
projectMovedDB.setDetails(new HashSet<>());
```

[works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1jff.jpg)
[don't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOouE.jpg)
Maybe someone have explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with breakpoint because sub entity (detail) connect to main entity Project  as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private Set<ProjectDetail> details = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Debugger call this  elements and LAZY grab it from DB, without debugger you could just get size (just for fill this variable):

```
Set<ProjectDetail> projectDetailsCurrent = projectMovedDB.getDetails(); 
projectDetailsCurrent.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reason of why you have a different behaviour with/without debug but:

- have you tried to flush only one time at the end?
- another option should to call projectRepository.clear() right after the first .flush()

Comment: Thanks Pilpo, for answering,  yes I tried use  flush only one time at the end.
I don't have method clear()  on my   projectRepository which extends from org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

Comment: Oh I just think of something else, instead of "Set<ProjectDetail> projectDetailsCurrent = projectMovedDB.getDetails();", try creating a new copy like that "Set<ProjectDetail> projectDetailsCurrent = new Set(projectMovedDB.getDetails());". Maybe there is something wrong with references in there. The "projectDetailsCurrent" is a reference to the old set, but after you flush, the old set is deleted. So you are referencing an empty set later on the "mergeSet()".

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue trying to figureout why data was only being retrieving using debug mode. I realized the the way I was executing the project mvn spring-boot:run did not enable lazy mode. So invoking directly as JAR file or using default STS IDE to execute the spring boot app enabled hibernate lazy automatically.